# Save my Clash of Clans village to Game Center

Tags: games, game-center, clash-of-clans

My son was playing Clash of Clans on my iPhone in my Game Center. I then started playing it but never saved it to my Game Center and now it says if I want to save it I  will have to go to his level. I transferred his to his iPod.

My question is how can I save mine to my Game Center now without going backwards to his village ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, you can't.. Clash of Clans allows you to have 1 village per Game Center account. And they don't allow you to reset your village. The only thing you can do is creating a new Game Center account with another Apple ID..


Source [Supercell Game Support](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/202564123-Save-your-village-with-Game-Center)